# Comparation jQuery and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my job I was asked to do a comparison table between these two libraries ... So I started reading about this but all I found was people saying "mobile its for ... mobile and jQuery its for desktop browsers" so ... Any one can help me to do a comparison table of characteristics and functionality of those two? Its this possible? Its really important for me to do this comparison!

Comment: You can google for 'jquery cheat cheet' and 'jquery mobile cheat cheet'. There're a lot of this tables and you can use this to compare the features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really isn't a comparison because they are not competing libraries.  JQuery Mobile is a HTML 5 based UI framework built on top of the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries.  You can't use jQuery Mobile *without* jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is ridiculous...jQuery mobile is dependent on jQuery. Do some homework

Comment: Im sorry if you found it ... ofensive! I know you are right but before telling my boss that this was imposible to do ... I preffer to be completely sure about it... Perhaps I could have been missing something. Take it easy ...